# Is including unused JavaScript files a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, performance, include

I use jQuery in lots of websites, for obvious reasons. So I simply include it in a `header.php` file. I also include other JavaScript libraries so in the end I get something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/classes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/common.js"></script>
```

There are sometimes even more includes, and some of them I use only in 1-2 pages. Is it good practice to include these JavaScript files in every other page too? Will it decrease performance? I mean, I know that they have to be downloaded for the first time, but they will be cached after it, won't they? **So how does only including (without using it) affect the performance? How do the cached files change the situation?**

If it affects performance, should I do something like:

```php
<?php if (JSFileNeeded) { ?>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/classes.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

What other techniques can I use to get rid of unused file includes?

Comment: Once the scripts are cached properly, there should be difference in subsequent page visits. The page most affected is the first virgin page visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `requireJS` for all your javascript dependency needs: http://requirejs.org/. Its possibly a more elegant solution than using backend code to turn on and off script tags.

Either way it is generally a bad idea to include files that are unused, even if they're cached they still take up memory. If they're not cached then extra connections and more bits over the wire will slow down your pages.

On a broadband connection unused files are unlikely to make much difference. But if the page is viewed on a phone over an intermittent data connection then it could make the page slow or even fail to load.

Comment: There is also the risk of included-but-unused scripts altering/destroying data in the global namespace or running unwanted global code.

Comment: That risk is still there even if the code in the files is used.

Comment: It is, but it is more likely to be missed when the script in question isn't there "for a reason".